# Note 3 - Apps Killed

Tags: root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have a rooted Note 3:

- Samsung-SM-N900A (AT&T)
- Android 4.3
- Baseband N900AUCUBNB4

The issue I'm having is that there is something that's killing applications that should be running in the background.

For example, the Alarm Clock. Daily, 7:00 am alarm is set. The alarm never goes off because the application has been killed.

The "battery saver" mode is disabled.

What else is there that I can do to remove Samsung's propensity to kill apps on my Note 3? My phone is rooted, are there Samsung Apps that I can kill/freeze? Is there any options that force an app to keep running?

Comment: are you using `greenify` or any _app hibernation_  ??

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of an option in developers settings which limit the amount of background processes. Is this option set to anything besides standard limit? Aside from an app killer application I can think of nothing else except crazy OOM settings.

Comment: "Standard Limit" is what that is set to. Options are `0-4 processes at most`

Comment: Poking around at OOM settings. Rom Toolbox Pro has a memory manager, and apparently it allows me to lower the OOM setting on it. It went from something to -17, which should hopefully keep it alive. I'll update if I notice anything.

Comment: Sounds good. If that doesn't do anything then perhaps check some of your other root apps if you haven't already. They may be imposing some of their "performance" enhancements.